# Get collection of object.getSomething() from this object collection

Tags: java, collections

Let's say I have a `Collection<MyObject>` and I want to get a new collection of something like `Collection<Integer>` with `myObjects.getIntValues()`. Can I make this fast and clear instead of making new Collection and iterate through all the collection members and add `MyObject.getIntValue()` to the new collection?

```
List<Int> list = new ArrayList<Int>;
for(MyObject obj : myCollection) {
    list.add(obj.getIntValue());
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can create your own collection doing this - Java collections don't support implicit casting of a whole collection and returning a new one.

Comment: Which version of Java? 6/7/8 ?

Comment: 6. but i would love to hear about more modern solutions too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example with Java 8 streams:

```
final List<Object> objects = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
final List<Integer> integers = objects.stream()
        .map(o -> (Integer) o)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: ok, streams look well. how about more obsolte soultion? for ex. java 6

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [copy Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#copy(java.util.List,%20java.util.List)) of the `Collection` class if you just want a new collection of the same values as in the original one.

If you want to create a new collection with different values than in your original collection though (`MyObject.getIntValue()`), then I don't see a workaround for iterating through all your objects and programatically put the value into your new collection.

Be careful with the first variant though, as it only creates a shallow copy (the objects will be the same, only the references will be copied).